# Implementing Number Sort with Append Function in Scheme

Tags: sorting, scheme

I've been really stuck on implementing this function for some time, now, and cannot find the right resource to help me out further.

I am trying to implement a number sort, that sorts values in a list in ascending order.

My current implementation is:

```
(define num-sort
 (lambda (ls)
    (if(null? (cdr ls))
        ls
     (if(< (car ls) (cadr ls))
        (append (car ls) (num-sort(cdr ls)))
     (if(> (car ls) (cadr ls))
        (append (num-sort(cdr ls)) (car ls))
      (num-sort(cdr ls))
      )))))
```

I've been having an EXTREMELY rough time with scheme and understanding logically how things are done.

My "Append" function is a function I implemented prior to this, and it appears to work as intended:

```
(define append
  (lambda (ls1 ls2)
    (if (null? ls1)
     ls2
     (if (pair? ls1)
     (cons (car ls1) (append (cdr ls1) ls2))
      (cons ls1 ls2)))))
```

I understand there is a problem with the recursion, here, in that when I compare two elements and decide to do another recursive call, it completely screws up the order entirely - however I'm not sure how to fix this.

In my head, what I'm thinking of doing is assembling a list by comparing each element to neighboring elements. Normally, I'd try doing this by storing and accessing indices of an array/variables in another language, but I can't wrap my head around how to sort properly in this one.

Comment: Which [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) are you trying to implement?

Comment: Anything except insertion sort. I'm not sure how to implement a bubble or merge sort with this.

Comment: Then you could use for instance the implementation of Quicksort found in this [page](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs355/Handouts/schemedoc/schemedoc/node16.html).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to get a feel for that. Is it advantageous to know how to implement those two sorting algorithms in Scheme at all?

Comment: @ChristopherKelly The only reason bubble sort is taught to beginners is so they can practice loops. It's a very bad algorithm, not suited for recursion at all, and shouldn't be used for anything except teaching beginners about loops. Merge sort, on the other hand, is efficient and naturally recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to implement Selection Sort, here's a start:

```
(define (num-sort ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      ls
      (num-sort-helper (car ls) '() (cdr ls))))


(define (num-sort-helper min-so-far checked unchecked)
    # min-so-far is no bigger than anything in checked
    # nothing in unchecked has been looked at

    # return a list made up of min-so-far and the elements of 
    # checked and unchecked such that that first element returned 
    # is no bigger than anything else in that list

    # For example, (num-sort-helper 5 '(6 9 7) '(8 2 3)) returns 
    # a list of all 7 numbers with 2 at the beginning

  (cond ((null? unchecked) ???)               # nothing is bigger than min-so-far
        ((<= min-so-far (car unchecked)) ???) # min-so-far is still the "winner"
        (else ???)))                          # (car unchecked) is now the "winner"
```